# Unable to migrate guest: Unsafe migration: Migration may lead to data corruption if disks use cache != none

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I tried to migrate the virtual machine using virt-manager but  I am getting the error as
"Unable to migrate guest: Unsafe migration: Migration may lead to data corruption if disks use cache != none"

Answer (score 3):

As error says, you should have cache mode == none. You can make use of the virt-manager to do this.

1. Connect to the kvm guests from virt-manager.
2. Open the guest (the virtual machine you want to migrate) window. go to "show virtual hardware details" > IDE DISK * > Expand the Advanced options > Expand performance options > set the cache mode to none > Click on apply.
3. You may need to restart you virtual machine in order to migrate.
4. After rebooting your virtual machine.. you can migrate the vm to destination host normally.